# how to set imagepicker.tag=value in imagepicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i m new in iphone sdk and when i set imagepicker.tag=vaule(100) then it produce a error so anyone help me to solve this problem

```
   `  imagepicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagepicker.delegate=self;
    imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];`
```

Comment: I think,  UIImagePickerController does not have a tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
imagepicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];
imagepicker.view.tag = 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

`tag` is a property of `UIView`. `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. It does not have a `tag` property.

Comment: That would work but I wouldn't advise it. `imagepicker.view` belongs to the image picker and you shouldn't interfere with it. There is no way to know whether the image picker itself would want to use the `tag` property of its view (albeit unlikely) or if the picker decides to replace its view with another object (unlikely, too). In both cases, your code would fail. It's just not good design.